outside fuel tank door does not lock
I have 2011 Honda CRZ and the gas door does not lock. It seems that dingy thing shown in the picture is broken and I have no idea what is it called so I can search for that part.
Can someone please help me identify what is it called?


According to honda parts now web site, the part is called Cable, Fuel Lid Opener and is available at the linked site. Photo from linked site (not too helpful)


I can't imagine what a  PITB that thing would be to replace ... argh.

this looks like just the dingy thing: https://www.hondapartsnow.com/genuine/honda~lifter~fuel~lid~push~74486-tf0-013.html without the cable.
